# R, find character string from vector, create new TRUE/FALSE columns

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame like this:

```
df<-structure(list(MRN = c("53634", "65708", "72122", "40458", "03935", 
"67473", "20281", "52479", "10261", "40945", "40630", "92295", 
"43505", "80719", "39492", "44720", "70691", "21351", "03457", 
"02182"), Outcome_Diagnosis_1 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Seroma of breast [N64.89]", 
"Breast implant capsular contracture [T85.44XA]; Breast implant capsular contracture [T85.44XA]; Breast implant capsular contracture [T85.44XA]", 
NA, NA, NA, "Acquired breast deformity [N64.89]", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, "Acquired breast deformity [N64.89]", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), Outcome_Diagnosis_2 = c(NA, NA, NA, "Extrusion of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.49XA]; Extrusion of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.49XA]; Extrusion of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.49XA]", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Capsular contracture of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.44XD]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.44XD]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, subsequent encounter [T85.44XD]", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Outcome_Diagnosis_3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Acquired breast deformity [N64.89]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.44XA]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.44XA]; Capsular contracture of breast implant, initial encounter [T85.44XA]", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I have a few vectors like this:

```
Infection<-c("L76","L00", "L01","L02","L03","L04", "L05","L08")
Hematoma<-c("N64.89","M79.81")
Seroma<- c("L76.34")
Necrosis<- c("N64.1","T86.821")
CapsularContracture<- c("T85.44")
MechanicalComplications<- c("T85", "T85.4", "T85.41", "T85.42", "T85.43", "T85.49")
```

What I'd like to do is create new columns in the data frame that are `TRUE`/`FALSE` for if that vector was found in each row.  (And it would just be TRUE even if it shows up multiple times in that row, i.e. it doesn't need to "count" them).

So the output I want would be something like this:
[image]

The reason I am struggling and came to stack for help is I don't really know how to combine searching for particular strings (that might be within a longer sentence in that column) and looking over multiple columns.

**Additional Info that might be important:**

- There are more columns than just those 3 outcome diagnoses, it'd be useful if the answer looked through the entire row regardless of how many columns
- Sometimes those codes aren't specific enough and it'd probably be useful to look for the actual words like "Seroma".  I imagine that'd just be a case of swapping out the characters inside the quotes right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store your vectors in a list:

```
lst <- list(Infection = c("L76","L00", "L01","L02","L03","L04", "L05","L08"),
            Hematoma = c("N64.89","M79.81"),
            Seroma = c("L76.34"),
            Necrosis = c("N64.1","T86.821"),
            CapsularContracture = c("T85.44"),
            MechanicalComplications = c("T85", "T85.4", "T85.41", "T85.42", "T85.43", "T85.49"))
```

And then, using `dplyr` and `purrr` you could do:

```
imap(lst,
     ~ df %>%
      mutate(!!.y := reduce(across(Outcome_Diagnosis_1:Outcome_Diagnosis_3, function(y) grepl(paste(sub("\\.", "", .x), collapse = "|"), sub("\\.", "", y))), `|`))) %>%
 reduce(full_join)

   MRN   Outcome_Diagnos… Outcome_Diagnos… Outcome_Diagnos… Infection Hematoma Seroma Necrosis CapsularContrac…
   <chr> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <lgl>     <lgl>    <lgl>  <lgl>    <lgl>           
 1 53634 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 2 65708 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 3 72122 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 4 40458 Seroma of breas… Extrusion of br… <NA>             FALSE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 5 03935 Breast implant … <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    TRUE            
 6 67473 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 7 20281 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 8 52479 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
 9 10261 Acquired breast… <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE    FALSE           
10 40945 <NA>             <NA>             <NA>             FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE
```

Comment: Be careful with your `grepl`, there are `.` dots in the strings which may produce false-positives.

Comment: @r2evans I see, it was a tricker problem that I originally thought :)

Comment: Apparently OP doesn't care (not too likely)?

Comment: @r2evans I think they do, they just didn't experience the problem yet.

Comment: (It's not a problem until it is. And that will be a hard one to find if they aren't looking hard at the regex implications.)

Answer (score 3):

### Up front

```r
out <- lapply(manythings, function(thing) {
  rowSums(
    do.call(cbind, lapply(df[,2:4], function(col) Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(thing, col, fixed = TRUE)))
  ) > 0
})
tibble(cbind(df, out))
# # A tibble: 20 x 10
#    MRN   Outcome_Diagnosis_1   Outcome_Diagnosis_2   Outcome_Diagnosis_3   Infection Hematoma Seroma Necrosis CapsularContrac~ MechanicalCompl~
#    <chr> <chr>                 <chr>                 <chr>                 <lgl>     <lgl>    <lgl>  <lgl>    <lgl>            <lgl>           
#  1 53634 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  2 65708 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  3 72122 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  4 40458 Seroma of breast [N6~ Extrusion of breast ~ <NA>                  FALSE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            TRUE            
#  5 03935 Breast implant capsu~ <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    TRUE             TRUE            
#  6 67473 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  7 20281 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  8 52479 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
#  9 10261 Acquired breast defo~ <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 10 40945 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 11 40630 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 12 92295 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 13 43505 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 14 80719 Acquired breast defo~ Capsular contracture~ Acquired breast defo~ FALSE     TRUE     FALSE  FALSE    TRUE             TRUE            
# 15 39492 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 16 44720 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 17 70691 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 18 21351 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 19 03457 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE           
# 20 02182 <NA>                  <NA>                  <NA>                  FALSE     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE            FALSE
```

### Walk-through

Same as @tmfmnk, I recommend putting all of your patterns into a named list:

```r
manythings <- list(
  Infection = c("L76","L00", "L01","L02","L03","L04", "L05","L08"),
  Hematoma = c("N64.89","M79.81"),
  Seroma =  c("L76.34"),
  Necrosis =  c("N64.1","T86.821"),
  CapsularContracture =  c("T85.44"),
  MechanicalComplications =  c("T85", "T85.4", "T85.41", "T85.42", "T85.43", "T85.49"))
```

Also, we should note that while `grepl` is good for this, it does not vectorize the `pattern=` argument, so we need to do that externally. Further, since some of your patterns have regex-sensitive characters (i.e., `.` which matches anything), we need to guard against regex-injection. For instance, if we aren't careful, then `"N64.89"` as a pattern will incorrectly match `"N64989"`. For this, I use `fixed=TRUE` as a safeguard. Unfortunately, this also hampers our ability to shape the patterns such that we can check for all of them in one step. Instead, we'll vectorize it, searching a fixed-regex (single element of one of your vectors of patterns) and aggregate the results.

So let's do one of the pattern-vectors against one column of the frame:

```r
Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(manythings[[2]], df[[2]], fixed = TRUE)
#       N64.89 M79.81
#  [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [2,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [3,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [4,]   TRUE  FALSE
#  [5,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [6,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [7,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [8,]  FALSE  FALSE
#  [9,]   TRUE  FALSE
# [10,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [11,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [12,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [13,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [14,]   TRUE  FALSE
# [15,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [16,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [17,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [18,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [19,]  FALSE  FALSE
# [20,]  FALSE  FALSE
```

Now we can reduce that so that we know of *one* of the patterns is found within each cell of this one column:

```r
rowSums(
  Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(manythings[[2]], df[[2]], fixed = TRUE)
) > 0
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Now we can iterate that process over each of the vectors of patterns within `manythings`:

```r
lapply(manythings, function(thing) {
  rowSums(
    Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(thing, df[[2]], fixed = TRUE)
  ) > 0
})
# $Infection
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $Hematoma
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $Seroma
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $Necrosis
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $CapsularContracture
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# $MechanicalComplications
#  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

All of this has been to a single column, `df[[2]]`. In order to apply this across multiple (selectable) columns, I'll employ some tricks with column-binding (in the code at the top). To break that down,

- `lapply(df[,2:4], ...)` subsets the data we want to search so just a few columns. Any way you want to select columns will fit here. This will return a `list` of matrices, something like:

  ```r
  lapply(df[,2:4], function(col) Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(thing, col, fixed = TRUE))
  # $Outcome_Diagnosis_1
  #       N64.89 M79.81
  #  [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [2,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [3,]  FALSE  FALSE
  # ...
  # $Outcome_Diagnosis_2
  #       N64.89 M79.81
  #  [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [2,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [3,]  FALSE  FALSE
  # ...
  # $Outcome_Diagnosis_3
  #       N64.89 M79.81
  #  [1,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [2,]  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [3,]  FALSE  FALSE
  # ...
  ```
- `do.call(cbind, ...)` will take each of those embedded matrices and combine them into a single matrix:

  ```r
  do.call(cbind, lapply(df[,2:4], function(col) Vectorize(grepl, vectorize.args = "pattern")(thing, col, fixed = TRUE)))
  #       N64.89 M79.81 N64.89 M79.81 N64.89 M79.81
  #  [1,]  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [2,]  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [3,]  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  #  [4,]   TRUE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE  FALSE
  # ...
  ```

  which allows us to use `rowSums(.) > 0` to determine if any patterns (in each column) is met for each row.

Comment: Never used function `Vectorize` before, I see in this setting it could save some lines of code :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another **base R** solution you could use albeit similar to some extent. As pointed out cleverly by dear @r2evans I also changed my pattern matching to `fixed = TRUE` which I was not aware of in the first place:

```
cbind(df, as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, lst |>
                                  lapply(function(a) {
                                    sapply(a, function(b) {
                                      apply(df[-1], 1, function(c) as.logical(Reduce(`+`, grepl(b, c, fixed = TRUE))))
                                    }) |>  rowSums() |> as.logical()
                                  }))))

   Infection Hematoma Seroma Necrosis CapsularContracture MechanicalComplications
1      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
2      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
3      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
4      FALSE     TRUE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                    TRUE
5      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE                TRUE                    TRUE
6      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
7      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
8      FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
9      FALSE     TRUE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
10     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
11     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
12     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
13     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
14     FALSE     TRUE  FALSE    FALSE                TRUE                    TRUE
15     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
16     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
17     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
18     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
19     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
20     FALSE    FALSE  FALSE    FALSE               FALSE                   FALSE
```

In order to accommodate the result I only put the output of newly created columns here, but the code binds them to the original data set.

```
lst <- list(Infection = c("L76", "L00", "L01", "L02", "L03", "L04", 
"L05", "L08"), Hematoma = c("N64.89", "M79.81"), Seroma = "L76.34", 
    Necrosis = c("N64.1", "T86.821"), CapsularContracture = "T85.44", 
    MechanicalComplications = c("T85", "T85.4", "T85.41", "T85.42", 
    "T85.43", "T85.49"))
```